# How do I view the log of a previous failure for an OpenShift Job?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a Job that runs daily with its container having a `restartPolicy` of `onFailure`. It failed once, then ran again about 40 mins later. We need to know the reason for the failure, but `oc logs` only brings up the log of the *successful* run.

Is there a way to bring up the log for the previous *failed* run?

Comment: I _think_ `oc logs -p` will give you what you want...or I've seen it work, it may not work in all scenarios, but give it a shot!

Comment: Did you try to check 'oc get event'? How to do it can be found in [OC Documentation][1]. Also could you confirm, that this job dont have `activeDeadlineSeconds` setting? Is it possible to post here `Job` YAML?